# Using enscript, need first line to be of different font size

Tags: enscript

I'm using enscript piped to ps2pdf to convert text files to pdf. The content of the file is the result of an SQL query with column names serving as header. I'm already using -B to eliminate default file name header, -r for landscape format and -fCourier7 for smaller font size (I don't want the lines to be wrapped).

However I find that though font size 7 is good for the header, for the rest of the content the font size could be bigger. Is there an option in enscript that enables a separate font size for the first row?